# how to append selected input value to anoter div in Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autosuggest

hi i am using `Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery` library

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

there are 2 demos there .

in the first demo (Ajax auto-suggest sample (start typing country name))

when you select a country from the drop down that country and a image is added to a div 
like this

```
<div id="selection"><img alt="" src="/global/flags/small/ht.png"> Haiti</div>
```

the selected dropdown value is `Haiti` how can i do this .

i want to do this when `mouse clicking` on  drop-down value and also when `press enter` on selected drop-down value .

i tried but could not think a way ................. please help  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `autocomplete`-parameters you can define an `onSelect` callback. Add the function to change the `div` with the id `selection`. E.g.:

```
$(>selector<).autocomplete({
    ...
    onSelect: function(value, data) {
        $('#selection').html('<img src="/global/flags/small/' + data + '.png" alt="" /> ' + value);
    }
    ...
});
```